# Using Entity Registration, how can I create a view that shows all the events that a user has NOT registered for?

Tags: views

Using the [Entity Registration](https://drupal.org/project/registration) module's built-in Views integration, I was easily able to create a view showing the events that the logged-in user has registered as attending.

Content type: Event
Date field
Registration field

I created a view of **registrations** with a relationship of **registration to node**.

Now, however, I would like to create a list of the content type **event** but only show those events for which the logged-in user has not registered.

I can add a relationship **node to registration**, but I don't know how to structure the filter to remove the events for which the logged-in user has registered.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for something like [this feature](https://drupal.org/node/1349922) - sadly, it is not implemented (yet?). Problem is, SQL does not support anti-joins in any reliable generic way, so most of generic solutions built on top of SQL databases can't do it, either. Materials I used to code similar case (or similar ones) are still to be found under this search: https://www.google.pl/search?q=sql+anti-join

Comment: @Mołot I see, thanks for that link.  Hmmm, then I suppose I'll have to add something to the module like this: https://drupal.org/node/2085425.  That code works, but not in Views.

Comment: If you have code that works, I think I have a way to add it to Views, for one specific case but anyway. Posted an answer, feel free to edit it with code from linked issue or clarify me on table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it will be hard.

Seems like you are looking for something like [this feature](https://drupal.org/node/1349922) - sadly, it is not implemented (yet?). Problem is, SQL does not support anti-joins in any reliable generic way, so most of generic solutions built on top of SQL databases can't do it, either. Materials I used to code similar case (or similar ones) are still to be found under this search: http://google.pl/search?q=sql+anti-join

Maybe there is a way to create view like that. If you only want it to work when view is filtered by one user, you could implement [`hook_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7). Use [`->hasTag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/QueryAlterableInterface%3a%3ahasTag/7) to determine if query came from the view you want to alter, and then [`->conditions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface%3a%3aconditions/7) to make sure it shows results for just one user (to avoid things getting messy). Then you can outer join appropriate table and (if it's our usual many-to-many intermediate table), only select rows where registration entry [`->isNull()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface%3a%3aisNull/7).